# Expectation of Integral

Tags: probability-theory, measure-theory, expected-value, stochastic-calculus, stochastic-integrals

For $a>0$ and a r.v. $X$, is it true that $\int_0^\infty a^{p-1} \mathbb{P}[{{X}\ge a}] \operatorname{d}a = \mathbb{E}[{\int_0^{{X}}a^{p-1}\operatorname{d}a}]$? If so, why?

Answer (score 1, accepted):

$\int_0^\infty a^{p-1} \mathbb{P}[{{X}\ge a}] \operatorname{d}a = \int_0^\infty a^{p-1} \int_{\mathbb{R}}I_{[x\ge a]}d \mathbb{P}(x) \operatorname{d}a $
and by Fubini's theorem
$$ \int_0^\infty a^{p-1} \int_{\mathbb{R}}I_{[x\ge a]}d \mathbb{P}(x)  \operatorname{d}a =\int_{\mathbb{R}}   \int_0^\infty  a^{p-1}  I_{[x\ge a]}\operatorname{d}a  d \mathbb{P}(x) = \mathbb{E}\left[{\int_0^{{X}}a^{p-1}\operatorname{d}a}\right].$$